# stream into img ionic and angular2, miss frames

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, rtsp

I developed an app to see the stream of my home cameras directly on the smartphone,but I have a problem:

- When I view the cameras the speed has increased and I can not figure out if it is a frame loss or other.
  this is the code I use to take the stream of cameras directly from rtsp link.

where the stream is a variable that changes at each switch.

if I see them from browsers you see very well.

```
getStream() {
    let _id = this.channels[this.selected].id_cam;

    return this.service.stream(_id);
}

  stream(id) {
    return this.endPoint + 'cam/' + id + '?userid=' + Global.userid + '&token=' + Global.token;
  }
```

Browser:

```
<ion-img id="imgStream" [src]="getStream()"></ion-img>
```

OR:

```
<ion-img id="imgStream" [src]="stream"></ion-img>
```

Comment: try `<ion-img id="imgStream" [src]="{{getStream()}}"></ion-img>`

Comment: @ewizard Parse error

Comment: just another idea....store `getStream()` in a variable and use that in the bindings... `x;           this.x = getStream() { ... }` and try `[src]="{{x}}"`

Comment: @ewizard I've already tried it, I also wrote it on and yet {{x}} is not a proper syntax

Comment: yah i thought maybe it would accept a variable instead of a function with `()` for the parse error....and yah my bad...it would be `[src]='x'` if it worked

Comment: have you just tried storing `this.service.stream(_id)` in a variable and just referencing that with `[src]`?

Comment: yes you not read?

Comment: `stream` isn't a variable

Comment: the result is the same